# Unable to plot stacked barplot using R Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I am new to R Shiny. Actually i have drawn `Stacked Barplot` using `ggplot` in my 
R code. I want to draw the same using shiny. Below is my R code:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = OutPut, y = Group, fill = Group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid(~ Environment)
```

In my R code it is giving correct results.But i am trying to draw in `shiny`. Below is my shiny R code.

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("lumen"),
                titlePanel("Data Analysis"),
                selectInput("variable", "Variable:", c("OutPut", "Member", "Levels")),
                mainPanel(plotOutput("plot")))

# Define server function
server <- function(input, output){
  x = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = variable.names(), y = Group, fill = Group)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    facet_grid(~ Environment)
  plot(x)
}

# Create Shiny object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It is throwing an error,here i have created a dropdown box where all the variables have been stored. So when i select one variable, it should plot the `Stacked barplot`. Could anyone please help me.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what do you mean by when you select one variable, a stacked plot?

Comment: See ?reactiveValues   and  http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#reactivity

Comment: Within the server function, you need to wrap the plot in a renderPlot function - see https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/renderPlot.html

Answer (score 0):

Like it was mentioned in the comments, you need to use the rendering functions and actually assign them to the output to get the outputs you need.

I believe an example of using plots in rshiny would help, since it wouldn't make sense to have it in the comments, here it is:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Fast Example with mtcars"),
                # inputs
                selectInput("x", "Choose x:", choices = names(mtcars), selected = 'mpg'),
                selectInput("y", "Choose y:", choices = names(mtcars), selected = 'hp'),
                selectInput("fill", "Choose fill:", choices = names(mtcars), selected = 'carb'),

                mainPanel(
                  #outputs
                  h2("Chosen variables are:"),
                  h4(textOutput("vars")),
                  plotOutput("plot")))


server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- mtcars

# here's how you would use the rendering functions 
# notice that I used aes_string   
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=df, 
           aes_string(x= input$x, y= input$y, fill=input$fill)) + 
      geom_point()
  })

  output$vars <- renderText(paste0('x: ', input$x, " , ", 
                                   'y: ', input$y, " , ", 
                                   'fill: ', input$fill))

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The Rshiny tutorial is pretty helpful, you can take a look at it here https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/